# Retrieve only data which have been modified - checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox

I have an UltraGrid with checkboxes columns.

There are initialized from a web method in Java which is calling the DB for the data. Anyway, when I run the application some checkboxes are already filled and I can check or uncheck.
I would like to retrieve the columns which have been updated. Currently, I did something which allows me to retrieve the status of all the checkboxes and not only the ones I've modified.

Here's the code, the method GetStatusForRow retrieve the status of the checkboxes and GetStatusCheckboxes call the previous method to get the status of all the checkboxes.

```
public partial class FrmCVault : Form
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Base filter lists
    /// </summary>
    //TODO: Change to a CVaultConfiguration Class
    public List<BASEFILTER> lBaseFilters { get; private set; }
    public List<SITE> lSites { get; private set; }
    public List<CONFIGURE> lConfigures{ get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public FrmCVault()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.lBaseFilters = null;
        this.lSites = null;
        this.lConfigures = null;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private methods

    #region Compare byte[]

    /// <summary>
    /// Compare two byte[]
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="b1"></param>
    /// <param name="b2"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool Compare(byte[] b1, byte[] b2)
    {
       // return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b1) == Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b2);
        return b1.SequenceEqual(b2);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fill the table with Basefilter data

    /// <summary>
    /// Fill the table with Basefilter data
    /// </summary>
    private void retrieveData()
    {
        EVPTProviderBase provider = DataRepository.EVPTProvider;

        ObjectDataSet ds = provider.GetBaseFilter();

        if (ds != null)
        {
            this.lBaseFilters = ds.arBASEFILTER.ToList();
            this.lSites = ds.arSITE.ToList();
            this.lConfigures = ds.arCONFIGURE.ToList();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Load Base filter data from DB
    /// <summary>
    /// Load data from the database 
    /// </summary>
    private void LoadDataSource()
    {
        CVaultDataSource.Rows.Clear();

        if (this.lBaseFilters != null)
        {
            var filters = from filterBase in this.lBaseFilters
                          orderby filterBase.EVPTCODE
                          select new { Id = filterBase.ID, cvault = filterBase.CVAULTCODE, evpt = filterBase.EVPTCODE, desc = filterBase.EVPTDESIGNATION, duration = filterBase.DURATION, time = filterBase.ETDTIME };

            var sitesDB = from sites in this.lSites
                          orderby sites.KEY
                          select new { SiteKey = sites.KEY, SiteId = sites.ID };

            var configs = from config in this.lConfigures
                          select new { site = config.SITE_ID, baseF = config.BASEFILTER_ID };

            object[][] table = new object[filters.Count()][];
            int i = 0;

            foreach (var item in filters)
            {
                int j = 0;
                table[i] = new object[5 + sitesDB.Count()];
                table[i][j++] = item.cvault;
                table[i][j++] = item.evpt;
                table[i][j++] = item.desc;
                table[i][j++] = item.duration;
                table[i][j++] = item.time;
                foreach (var site in sitesDB)
                {
                    table[i][j] = false;

                    foreach (var conf in configs)
                    {
                        if (Compare(site.SiteId, conf.site) && Compare(conf.baseF, item.Id))
                        {
                            table[i][j] = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            foreach (var item in table)
            {
                CVaultDataSource.Rows.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Add column sites

    /// <summary>
    /// Add columns in table according to the sites stored in DB
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>The action is used to create site column</remarks>
    private void AddColumnSites()
    {
        const string siteCol = "SITE_COL";

        var addNewSite = new Action<string>(site =>
        {
            if (siteCol != "OTHER") 
            {
                var ultraGridBand = this.CVaultGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0];

                var gridDataColumn = new UltraDataColumn(site);
                gridDataColumn.DataType = typeof(bool);
                gridDataColumn.Tag = siteCol;
                gridDataColumn.DataType = typeof(bool);
                gridDataColumn.DefaultValue = false;

                this.CVaultDataSource.Band.Columns.AddRange(new object[] {
                    gridDataColumn
                });
            }
        });

        for (int i = this.CVaultDataSource.Band.Columns.Count-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            if (this.CVaultDataSource.Band.Columns[i].Tag == siteCol)
            {
                this.CVaultDataSource.Band.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

        var sitesDB = from sites in this.lSites
                      orderby sites.KEY
                      select  sites.KEY ;

        foreach (var item in sitesDB)
        {
            addNewSite(item);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Retrieve status of checkboxes
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve the checkboxes's status of  the last row selected
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="b"></param>
    /// <param name="row"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Dictionary<string, bool> GetStatusForRow(UltraDataBand b, UltraDataRow row)
    {
        Dictionary<string, bool> statusChecked = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        foreach (UltraDataColumn col in b.Columns.Cast<UltraDataColumn>()
                                         .Where(x => x.Tag != null &&
                                                x.Tag.ToString() == "SITE_COL"))
        {
            statusChecked.Add(col.Key, Convert.ToBoolean(row.GetCellValue(col)));
        }
        return statusChecked;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Retrieve status of hours columns

    private Dictionary<string, string> GetStatusHoursForRow(UltraDataBand b, UltraGridRow row)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> statusChecked = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (UltraDataColumn col in b.Columns.Cast<UltraDataColumn>()
                                         .Where(x => x.Tag != null &&
                                                x.Tag.ToString() == "SITE_COL"))
        {
            //statusChecked.Add(,);
        }
        return statusChecked;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion

    #region Form Events

    /// <summary>
    /// Form loading event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Form</param>
    /// <param name="e">Arguments (empty)</param>
    private void FrmCVault_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        this.retrieveData();
        this.AddColumnSites();
        this.LoadDataSource();
        CVaultGrid.DataBind();
    }

    private void ultraButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CVaultGrid.ActiveRow.Update();
        CVaultGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].AddNew();
    }

    private void FrmCVault_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CVaultGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].AddNew();
    }

    private void vl_ItemNotInList(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        var ultrCombo = sender as UltraComboEditor;
        e.RetainFocus = true;

        if (e.LastValidValue != null)
            ultrCombo.Value = e.LastValidValue;
        else if (ultrCombo.Items.Count>0)
            ultrCombo.SelectedItem = ultrCombo.Items[0];
    }

    private void ultraGrid1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            CVaultGrid.UpdateData();
        }
    }

    private void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void SAVE_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.GetStatusCheckboxes();
        this.GetStatusHours();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the status of checkboxes which have been changed (check or uncheck)
    /// </summary>
    private void GetStatusCheckboxes()
    {
        var statusChecked = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>();
        foreach (UltraDataRow row in CVaultDataSource.Rows)
        {
            statusChecked.Add(row.GetCellValue(0).ToString(), GetStatusForRow(CVaultDataSource.Band, row));
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, bool>> kvp in statusChecked)
        {
            foreach (var sr in kvp.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] Status site: {1} is {2}", kvp.Key, sr.Key, sr.Value));    
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get back the hour which have been updated
    /// From the column DURATION or ETD
    /// </summary>
    private void GetStatusHours()
    {
        //GetStatusHoursForRow(CVaultDataSource.Band, CVaultGrid.ActiveRow);
        //Dictionary<string, bool> statusChecked = GetStatusForRow(CVaultDataSource.Band, CVaultGrid.ActiveRow);
        //foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> kvp in statusChecked)
        //    Console.WriteLine("Status site:" + kvp.Key + " is " + kvp.Value.ToString());
        //Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
    }

    #endregion

    private void CVaultGrid_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Here's a screen to see the windows:

[image: Example of window]

Answer (score 0):

Better than check the status of the entire row to see if CheckBox of a column is SET or not is intercept ITS EVENT like:

```
Public Sub dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
Handles dataGridView1.CellValueChanged

If dataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "MyCheckBox" Then
    Dim checkCell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = _
        CType(dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("MyCheckBox"), _
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)

    Dim IsSet as boolean = checkCell.Value

    dataGridView1.Invalidate()
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: I need to retrieve status to update DB. I do not think what you wrote could help me. I'm using C#, not VB. I have currently a <key,value>. I need something similar but only for the ones which have been modified.

Comment: Your post did not mentioned it clearly and the above routine just allows you to know, via EVENT, whenever someone check/uncheck determined column, allowing you to update the DB manually if needed.  The conversion from VB to C# is seamless and, if prefered, you may convert it automatically using for instance the Telerik link (http://converter.telerik.com/). Anyway, if cannot help you, I´m sorry...

Comment: You're right, my bad.
I'll try to do what I could with what you wrote. Thank anyways :)

Comment: A man should never be ashamed to acknowledge you were wrong, as this is to say that today is wiser than it was yesterday - Jonathan Swift.  Good luck and have a nice weekend.  :)